# Updating csi-driver without stopping

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, csi-driver

I'm now facing this.

```
  # module.eks_volume_provisioning.aws_eks_addon.csi_driver will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_eks_addon" "csi_driver" {
      ~ addon_version            = "v1.25.0-eksbuild.1" -> "v1.28.0-eksbuild.1"
        id                       = "kmx-dev:aws-ebs-csi-driver"
        tags                     = {}
        # (7 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

this is my terraform plan output.
It wants to update csi-driver to a newer one.

I'm curious that it would update csi-driver without stopping.
Is it possible to affect my services that are using persistent volume?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Is it possible to affect my services that are using persistent volume?

   **No**. CSI (no matter whether you are using EBS-CSI or EFS-CSI) only affects the process while you creating PV through a specific `storageClass`(handled by CSI). CSI won't get into it once the (persistent) PVC and PV are created.
2. Can you update csi-driver without stopping?

   **Yes**. You can update it without stopping the cluster, the `aws-csi-*` pod, or any running services. Any PVC that failed to be created during your CSI-Driver updating will automatically retry till its success.

   Well, maybe not. if that is so, just delete that PVC (and related pod) and bring it up again.